# C# OOP-2D array of object in separate class

Tags: c#, oop

im writing a simple chess game with c# and cant figure out what im doing wrong here. Box class represents a square on the board.

```
     public class Board
            {
                Box[,] boxes;
                public Board()
                {
                    Box[,] boxes = new Box[8, 8];
                    
                }
                public void Setpieces()
                {
                    this.boxes[0, 0].SetEmpty(false);
                }
```

then i create a board `Board boxes = new Board();`
and call setpieces `boxes.Setpieces();`
and i get an error saying object reference not set to an instance of an object.
im sure whatever ive done wrong is  obvious but ive spent a while trying to figure it out and cant get it, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `Box[,] boxes = new Box[8, 8];` doesnt instantiate all the `Box` instances in the array. It just allocates an array (of nulls, assuming `Box` is a reference type)

Comment: @TimothyG. unfortunately not, because i know the issue is the object is null, i just cant figure out why. it seems like my board class isnt being initialised, but im not sure why not.

Comment: In constructor you have set new local variable instead of your property one.

Change `Box[,] boxes = new Box[8, 8];` to  `boxes = new Box[8, 8];`

Comment: @xdjiijii , thanks for replying, ive just changed it to this public class Board
    {
        Box[,] boxes;
        public Board()
        {
            boxes = new Box[8, 8];
        }  and its given me a new error, "ambiguity between Board.boxes and Board.boxes"

Comment: Have another look at my comment above. `this.boxes[0, 0]` (and all other elements) are null when you try to call `SetEmpty` method

Comment: @Jamiec ok, i think i misunderstood originally, i will implement that now, thank you for reiterating